# AppleScript bug when using Myriad Tables Library: "types" is replaced with "type"

Tags: macos, applescript

I downloaded the Myriad Tables Lib v1.0.8 AppleScript script library from [here](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/Script_Libs.html).

Run the following code, and you will notice that the code will run without error:

```
-- use script "Myriad Tables Lib" version "1.0.8"
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"

on fetchStorableClipboard()
    set aMutableArray to current application's NSMutableArray's array() -- used to store contents
    -- get the pasteboard and then its pasteboard items
    set thePasteboard to current application's NSPasteboard's generalPasteboard()
    -- loop through pasteboard items
    repeat with anItem in thePasteboard's pasteboardItems()
        -- make a new pasteboard item to store existing item's stuff
        set newPBItem to current application's NSPasteboardItem's alloc()'s init()
        -- get the types of data stored on the pasteboard item
        set theTypes to anItem's types()
        -- for each type, get the corresponding data and store it all in the new pasteboard item
        repeat with aType in theTypes
            set theData to (anItem's dataForType:aType)'s mutableCopy()
            if theData is not missing value then
                (newPBItem's setData:theData forType:aType)
            end if
        end repeat
        -- add new pasteboard item to array
        (aMutableArray's addObject:newPBItem)
    end repeat
    return aMutableArray
end fetchStorableClipboard
```

Now, un-comment the very first line of this code:

`use script "Myriad Tables Lib" version "1.0.8"`

Once you compile your code, the following line:

```
set theTypes to anItem's types()
```

will automatically change to:

```
set theTypes to anItem's type {}
```

The issue is that **types** is changed to **type**. The effect is that this code no longer runs.

Does anyone know a workaround, or how to prevent this from occurring?

<sub>OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.6.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around this terminology conflict, use the following line:

```
set theTypes to anItem's |types|()
```

Here's more info (from [this webpage](http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/applescriptdefinitiveguide/applescpttdg2-CHP-7-SECT-4.html)):

> You can force an illegal variable name to be legal by surrounding it
>   with vertical bars, also known as "pipes."
>
> The real effect of pipes is to tell AppleScript to suspend its
>   compile-time parsing rules and turn what's inside the pipes into a
>   token. The main reason this is genuinely useful is to avoid a conflict
>   between a token name and a term already in use.

Note:

> A variable name surrounded by pipes is case-sensitive. AppleScript
>   will not touch the case of names in pipes after compilation.